# davidism's sandbox and misc apps

Tags: app, python

This app registration supports development environments for the following projects by enabling OAuth and API access locally:

- [**so**python](https://sopython.com) ([GitHub](https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site)) is the official website of the [Python chat on Stack Overflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).
- [shanty](https://bitbucket.org/davidism/shanty) is a mostly experimental Python wrapper for the Stack Exchange API and authentication.

Come visit the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) to see what we're up to.

[image: last-minute panic]

Comment: We don't seem to have a good mechanism, nor policy for private apps. May need a [meta](https://stackapps.com/tags/meta/info) question about such. (And, as far as I can tell, there are no surviving private app posts.) ... **Can you make this tool public? At least open-source the source code?**  If the answer to both of those is no, search around for previous private apps or policy and get back to me. (I did a quick search but don't have a lot of time now.)  If necessary, open a question about this and tag it `discussion` and `meta` (and any other appropriate tags).

Comment: The shanty link seems to be broken.