# PLACEHOLDER - Makyen development & testing

Tags: script, placeholder, testing

This is a placeholder for me to do development, testing and personal use. The intent is that no applications will be released beyond my own use using the credentials associated with this placeholder.

- 2019-09-04: Yes, this placeholder is still in use. Off the top of my head, the write tokens enabled by this placeholder have been/are being used for development and testing of [FIRE](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/userscripts/tree/master/fire). I'm vaguely recalling that I've used the write tokens permitted by this placeholder on at least another script or two over the course of this placeholder's existence, but I'm not remembering which one(s).

  While a placeholder post isn't necessary for an API key, the API key associated with this post is used on several different scripts while I've worked on them, including, but not limited to, the [Unclosed Request Review Script](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/UnclosedRequestReview.user.js), MagicTag2, [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se), and more. I edit and contribute to more than 50 different scripts associated with Stack Exchange. I don't recall all of the ones where I've used the API key associated with this post. Generally, I've done so in order to insulate the users of those scripts from any repercussions from changes I make in testing/development (i.e. if something goes very wrong and SE needed to shut off access for the API key used in a development version of a script, doing so would not affect the users of the released version).

Comment: Where can I find the link for the latest version of the script that shows the close & delete counts for CRUDE on math.SE?  I misplaced the old link and I couldn't find it by searching. Btw, will it work on Edge Canary?

Comment: Update: I  [found it](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts) but the installation method there doesn't seem to work for TamperMonkey on Edge Canary.  Is there some other way?

Comment: @BillDubuque The script you are looking for is the version of the [Unclosed Request Review Script which is for CRUDE](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/URRS-Mak-CRUDE-tmp-hack/UnclosedRequestReview.user.js). The direct install link is [here](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/raw/URRS-Mak-CRUDE-tmp-hack/UnclosedRequestReview.user.js). If you have Tampermonkey installed, you should be able to click on the direct install link and have it install. I'm not sure about Edge Canary specifically, but it has been tested on some versions of Edge.

Comment: I got it running but it only works on math.SE, not in the CRUDE chat room (TM says no scripts are running in CRUDE, but shows it running on math.SE). Any idea how to debug that?  I'm using the recently released Edge Canary for Win7 in case that matters.

Comment: @BillDubuque At this time, I don't have a good answer for you on that one. Did you install the script from the links I provided above? The version at those links works for me with Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0 under Windows 10. I don't currently have a Windows 7 instance spun up, so can't test it on that OS immediately. There's nothing in the Unclosed Request Review Script which would make it run on math.SE. It should *only* run in CRUDE and CRUDE Archive (use of CRUDE Archive is deprecated and that room is frozen), along with transcripts and searches associated with those rooms.

Comment: There is the [Request Generator](//github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts#user-content-so-close-vote-request-generator) (it's recommended that you use the alpha version ([GitHub](//github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/CVRG-Mak-new-version/SECloseVoteRequestGenerator.user.js)) ([install](//github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/raw/CVRG-Mak-new-version/SECloseVoteRequestGenerator.user.js)), unless using Greasemonkey 4 on Firefox). That script runs on Math.SE (and other SE main and meta sites), but should not run on SE's chat sites.

Comment: Update I tried again using your install link and now its working in CRUDE. Maybe it was a fluke having to do with TM on Edge.  Thanks much.

Comment: @BillDubuque np. I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: This was flagged as a stale placeholder. See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/7591) for more information.

Comment: @BrockAdams Please define how often "regularly edited" means. Without such a definition, I have to, and everyone else also has to, make an assumption as to how often that is. Obviously, with this post closed, I have to assume that it's at lest once every 9 days.

Comment: On the 9th day-ish, the post can be auto-deleted, but you can still get it undeleted and reopened with a good edit after that.  There's no official policy; see [this comment](https://stackapps.com/questions/6141/davidisms-sandbox-placeholder#comment17502_6141) and perhaps make a post to save me the trouble.  Personally, I'll not accept a new flag, for this reason, [for 14 days](https://stackapps.com/questions/7490/what-to-do-about-the-tsunami-of-placeholder-apps-created-because-of-a-poorly-wri#comment17239_7490) after a "good" edit. (Much Longer if it's not a placeholder anymore.)